# Dynamically load content inside a division on click of a button in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, single-page-application

I am trying to create an application with laravel and i am having some difficulty in understanding how to dynamically load content into a division according to the button clicked from the menu bar.

I have a top navigation bar, side navigation bar and a main content section on the home page.

I want the main content to change according to the option selected from the side navigation bar but i am not being able to find the solution.

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
 @section('title',  '| Homepage')

 @section('content')
  <div id="wrapper" class="active">

      <!-- Sidebar -->
            <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav">
               <li class="sidebar-brand">menu</li>
          </ul>
            @include('includes.sidebar')
      </div>

      <!-- Page content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
        <div class="page-content inset">
          <div class="row">
            <!--this part will change-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
@endsection
```

this is the home.blade.php. I have created it with layout and partial concept of laravel. i want to load a form in the main content area when the user request for it by clicking in the sidebar.

can anyone please help me with the how to do it?

Comment: I'm suggesting to use `javascript` or `jquery` to achieve your task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `onclick` event of a button to call a function when that button is clicked.

but first you have to define routes and views for your dynamic div content.
so

1. Create a view in `resources/views` folder like `main_content.blade.php` and put the code for your main content.
2. create a route in `routes/web.php` which will render the view we just created

   `Route::get("/main_content", function()
   {
      return View::make("main_content");
   });`
3. suppose you have a button similar to this in your sidebar.

   `<button onclick="load_main_content()" type="button">load</button>`

   also remember to assign an `id` to the div that should change like

   `<div class="row" id="main_content_div">
       <!--this part will change-->
     </div>`

   then function should be like this

   `<script type="text/javascript">
       function load_main_content()
       {
           $('#main_content_div').load('/main_content/');
       }
   </script>`

So now whenever the button is clicked the view should automatically load into the div.

*Hope this helps*

Comment: thank you for your reply.. it actually works but not they way i wanted to. probably i need to rephrase my question. My sidebar has drop down menus and sub-menus and all of them changes the view of the main content when clicked. Your method worked absolutely fine when i worked with one view. but somehow, it has some bugs for working with multiple view. 
I found a way to solve it. though it requires loading some parts every time a view is called. But for now it works fine.

thank you..

Comment: You should probably have a master layout which just has sidebar and other content which will remain constant across the application. and have the sidebar links point to multiple views for all your pages. You should also look into controller as they are quite necessary if you are planning to build a web application with logic and not just static site. Anyways you can accept the answer if you think it was right